# Why do I have to save all data in order for it to work?

Tags: matlab, file-writing

I’m working on a GUI in Matlab that reads in and processes a matrix from a sensor. You can choose the speed in which the matrix is written to a .txt file (frames/min, frames/sec, etc).

The matrix is saved in `data2d`. This is what I got:

```
% Record date when the time has come
if and(startLog == 1,time > recTime)
    for i=1:size(data2d,1)
        fprintf(fid, '%g\t', data2d(i,:));
        fprintf(fid,'\n');
    end
    fprintf(fid, '\n\n');
    time = 0;
    %Making sure you have choosen a unit and send out error
elseif and(startLog == 1,recTime == 0)
    set(handles.tag_txt3,'String','Choose a unit and start again');
    set(handles.tag_OnOff,'Value',0)
    set(handles.tag_log,'Value',0)
    counter = 0;
%default temp file
else
    for i=1:size(data2d,1)
    fprintf(fidDefault, '%g\t', data2d(i,:));
    fprintf(fidDefault,'\n');
    end
    fprintf(fidDefault, '\n\n');
end
```

As you can see I had to make a “default” file that saves the matrix every time it’s not being saved in the actual file (last `else`: `fidDefault` or `%default temp file`). If I don’t do that, nothing works anymore. I’ll get random errors like from lines where the matrix is created for example.

Does anyone know why that is or how I can fix it? Just so I don’t have a GB trash file after I let it run for a month or so?

Comment: Random errors like...what? Nobody but you can run this code and we're not omniscient.

Comment: When I read in the matrix and reshape it into 2d. It's always somewhere else (data(different number every time)) I get:    "Attempted to access data(49); index out of bounds because numel(data)=48.

Error in RackWriter>tag_OnOff_Callback (line 284)
                data2d(row_index(i), col_index(j)) = data(k);

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in RackWriter (line 21)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)RackWriter('tag_OnOff_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

 
Error while evaluating UIControl Callback"

Comment: I don't see `RackWriter` in your question statement.